# Extract top two sales team and save in a list, based on total sales without creating a separate column for it

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given is this dataFrame:

```
sales_data = pd.DataFrame({"rep1":["mark","amber","timothy"],
                          "rep2":["john","philip","max"],
                          "sales1":[300000,150000,280000],
                          "sales2":[200000,450000,195000]})
```

The output should be a list :

```
[['amber','philip'],['mark','john']]
```

Comment: Order is correct?

Comment: yes the order is correct

Answer (score 3):

First sum columns and for top2 use [`DataFrame.nlargest`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nlargest.html), last convert columns to list:

```
print (sales_data.assign(a = sales_data.sum(axis=1))
               .nlargest(2, 'a')[['rep1','rep2']]
               .to_numpy()
               .tolist())
[['amber', 'philip'], ['mark', 'john']]
```

If need output to variable:

```
L = (sales_data.assign(a = sales_data.sum(axis=1))
               .nlargest(2, 'a')[['rep1','rep2']]
               .to_numpy()
               .tolist())
print (L)
[['amber', 'philip'], ['mark', 'john']]
```

If need top2 values without helper column with [`Series.argsort`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.argsort.html) and [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
print (sales_data.iloc[-sales_data.sum(axis=1).argsort()[:2]])
    rep1    rep2  sales1  sales2
1  amber  philip  150000  450000
0   mark    john  300000  200000


print (sales_data.iloc[-sales_data.sum(axis=1).argsort()[:2], 
       sales_data.columns.get_indexer(['rep1','rep2'])]
                 .to_numpy()
                 .tolist())
[['amber', 'philip'], ['mark', 'john']]
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael but we still end up creating a variable. Is it not possible without any variable. Method chaining ?

Comment: amber and philip have highest sales, so they should come first. Before chaining to to_numpy() could I use sort_values() if nlargest() outputs a Series ?

Comment: @rhlchd - only remove `[::-1]`

Comment: @rhlchd - Answer was changed.

Comment: was looking at it part by part. 
If I remove `nlargest(2, 'a')[['rep1','rep2']].to_numpy().tolist()`, `sales_data.head()` shows a new column 'a' in the dataframe. Then how does it get removed?

Comment: @rhlchd - then use `sales_data.assign(a = sales_data.sum(axis=1)).nlargest(2, 'a').drop('a', axis=1)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want it in one liner, though it's really messy.

```
print(sales_data.iloc[sales_data.iloc[:,2:].sum(axis=1).nlargest(2).index].iloc[:,:2].values)
```

Output:

```
[['amber' 'philip']
 ['mark' 'john']]
```

This gives back a NumPy array actually. If you still want it in form of a list, simply do as how @jezrael has done:

```
print(sales_data.iloc[sales_data.iloc[:,2:].sum(axis=1).nlargest(2).index].iloc[:,:2].to_numpy().tolist())
```

This answer is kind of redundant after @jezrael's answer. Only benefit, it doesn't change the dataframe itsef.